# Speed of NSArray#count

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, count, nsarray

If I do

```
[myArray count]
```

is it O(1) or O(n), where n is the number of elements in the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code of Core Foundation collections (upon which Foundation collections are built) is open source. If you inspect [CFArray.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.42/CFArray.c), you’ll see that `__CFArrayGetCount()` is O(1).

Comment: -1; the way it's implemented now does not guarantee that it won't change.

Answer (score 3):

If it is not O(1) then you should find another array implementation :)

Comment: Apparently cocoa arrays are not "normal" arrays (see http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/), but count most likely is O(1)

Comment: -1; 'find another implementation' does not answer the question.